# CSS Layout info-box

Tags: html, css

my Problem is that I need in exactly that hierachy an infoBox that pops up on an event (it will be an click on button).
Div "Info" should be that. It should be independent on the parent-element.
So for example if I set top:0px; and left:0px; it should be at the top left of the browserwindow.
How to solve this?

```
<div style="postion:relative;float:left;margin-left:20px;margin-right:20px;">
  <div style="postion:relative;float:left;margin-top:100px">
    <div id="info" style="display:hidden;background-color:red"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Din you try out `position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px` to the info div so that you can have it anywhere ?

Comment: your div's position should be `position:relative` instead of `postion:relative;`. Try to make the `position:absolute` with the `top:0px` & `left:0px` properties for your `info` div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set position to absolute will always use the absolute position in Browser Window (e. g. top:0px; left:0px is top-left corner of Browser Window).